# JLabel.setText() not working after setting size

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jcomponent

I have a JLabel that I require to change dynamically when a button is pressed. I am using JLabel.setText(s)

However, it is not working. I've tried:

```
JLabel.repaint()
JLabel.validate()
JLabel.revalidate()
```

The thing I find strange is that it works fine when I don't set the size of the JLabel using any of:

```
JLabel.setPrefferedSize()
JLabel.setMinimumSize()
JLabel.setSize()
```

Can anyone help me with why it isn't working after I set one of the size properties?

Comment: Please, add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to your question.

Comment: It's very hard to guess what is wrong (and that's all we can do) based on the limited data provided. If none of the answers below answer your question satisfactorily, I too recommend that you create and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem,

I was using:

```
JLabel.setPreferredSize(100, JLabel.getheight());
```

I changed to:

```
JLabel.setPreferredSize(100, 22);
```

Comment: Most probably `getHeight()` returned `0` so your label didn't have the space to display correctly, and was thus not showing at all.

Answer (score 2):

What your button is doing is probably a very long task and you want to keep the user informed about the process.

To do this you have to create a new Thread which performs the long task and when you set new text to your label, wrap the `label.setText()` statement into an `invokeLater()`:

```
public void buttonAction()
{
   new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
       public void run()
       {
           // Here your long task

           // When you want to call Label.setText(), do it like this:
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
           {
               public void run()
               {
                   label.setText("Loading 1/13...");
               }
           });

           // Here another part of your task....

           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
           {
               public void run()
               {
                   label.setText("Done!");
               }
           });
       }
   }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For sizing components in Swing, ultimately the layout of the parent container has the final say on the size of the component.

For example, in `FlowLayout`, calling `setPreferredSize()`, `setSize()`, or `setMaximumSize()` on a component all have the result of giving the label that size, and not sizing over it. However, with `setMinimumSize()` it will start at that size, then size above it.

For `BorderLayout`, if the component is added to the center, none of the sizing methods affect the component - it just takes the maximum amount of space available.

If you set the layout of the parent container to `null` you can explicitly size components, however, you will lose the automatic resizing that you have with other layouts.

Answer (score -1):

> JLabel.setPreferredSize(100, JLabel.getheight());

As you are setting the preferred size here, the height of JLabel must not have been previously set :), if you try the same line after setting the height, I think it should work well.

Also sometimes `JPanel<xx>.updateUI();` is required to refresh the displayed UI.`enter code here`

Comment: updateUI is _not_ for use by application code! And [using setPreferredSize](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657) is extremely suboptimal (but wouldn't get a downvote in itself in the context of the QA which is a bit oldish)

Comment: what exactly updateUI is used for then? I have seen it work for refreshing my panels but I may be totally wrong.